# Send file to Network Printer by Javascript - Acrobat DC

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, acrobat

I have a trusted function that saves a file to my network printer. But it doesnt work, I get this error: "The file may be read-only, or another user may have it open. Please save the document with a different name or in a different folder."
This is my code:

```
var xerox = app.trustedFunction( function()
{
app.beginPriv();
var xeroxPath = "\\\out\\spool\\print\\Xerox\\";
this.saveAs(xeroxPath + this.documentFileName);
app.alert("PDF is sent to the printer",3)
app.endPriv();
});
```

Comment: Maybe check the function by running it line per line from the Console. I am in particular somewhat sceptical about the xeroxPath variable. In addition to that, try out the function when you are sue that the out folder is really empty.

Comment: You are right about the path Max!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. In windows map the  "\\out\spool\print\Xerox\" to a new network Drive. In my case I mapped it to X: so the code becomes:

```
var xerox = app.trustedFunction( function()
{ app.beginPriv();
var xeroxPath = "x:\\";
this.saveAs(xeroxPath + this.documentFileName);
app.alert("PDF is sent to the printer",3)
app.endPriv();
});
```